# How to include a seperate header file?

Tags: php, html, web, include

Hey so I am currently working on an html/php page.

I have a header file that I am supposed to include in my page but for some reason it's not working and I have no idea, I've done the same thing for all my other pages and it has worked so I don't know why all of a sudden its not working.

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
?>

<center>
<p>
This page utilizes several postgreSQL method calls.  Such as pg_connect(),
pg_query(), and pg_fetch_result().
</p>
<!-- setup the table -->
<table border="1" width="75%">
    <tr><th width="50%">Make</th><th width="15%">Model</th><th width="20%">Year</th><th width="15%">MSRP</th></tr>
<?php
$output = ""; //Set up a variable to store the output of the loop
//connect
$conn = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 dbname=slotegraafd_db user=slotegraafd password=100658347" );

//issue the query
$sql = "SELECT automobiles.make, automobiles.model, automobiles.year, automobiles.msrp
            FROM automobiles
            ORDER BY automobiles.year ASC";
    $result = pg_query($conn, $sql);
    $records = pg_num_rows($result);

//generate the table
    for($i = 0; $i < $records; $i++){  //loop through all of the retrieved records and add to the output variable
        $output .= "\n\t<tr>\n\t\t<td>".pg_fetch_result($result, $i, "Make")."</td>";
        $output .= "\n\t\t<td>".pg_fetch_result($result, $i, "Model")."</td>";
        $output .= "\n\t\t<td>".pg_fetch_result($result, $i, "Year")."</td>";
        $output .= "\n\t\t<td>".pg_fetch_result($result, $i, "msrp")."</td>\n\t</tr>";
    }

    echo $output; //display the output
?>
</table>
<!-- end the table -->
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my full set of code with the include statement. There is no opening html or body tag because it is in the header file therefore I am not supposed to add it in this page. 
Anyway any help?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the file path is correct. If this new file is in a folder, then you need to change your `include` statement.

For example, if this new file is in a folder called foo, you could say: `include '/foo/header.php`

Or you can use a relative path: `include ../header.php`

Read up on file paths if needed.

Comment: Glad to hear it! While you're looking at this, you may want to consider not putting the body tag in the header.php file. This might cause issues or confusion down the road. I only say something because I did this before, and found that it made the project more confusing later on.

Answer (score 0):

It should work just the way your code looks like. Maybe your path of header.php isnt correct, or the content can't be displayed / executed so it shows nothing.